# Hide bootstrap navigation items one by one

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a standard `bootstrap` `navbar` and there are two options or behaviours.

1. When the screen is wide enough then all menu elements are visible
2. When the screen is small then all elements go under the `hamburger icon`.

How can I create a third option to hide menu elements one by one if the screen is resizing until it reaches `mobile width`?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">More</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">More Menu</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Another One</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Third</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do standard Bootstrap display classes like d-none d-md-block in the navbar and just reverse that in the hamburger menu, d-md-none...

or media queries if you want a more specific screen size adjustment.